# java code make a stored procedure return a resultset in DAO layer

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that runs on MS SQL Server. It takes one parameter as input. Basically, it returns multiple rows. 
I am calling the SP from my java application by using **CallableStatement**.

I would like to know if it possible to get the rows returned by the stored procedure in the form of ResultSet in my DAO layer?[like how we get a resultset when we do **select * from EmployeeTable**] . If yes, how do we do that?

**P.S:** I don’t have privilege to modify the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server knows two types of procedures returning results:

#### Batches

The procedure looks something like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE p_results(
  @p_result_sets INT
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF @p_result_sets = 1 BEGIN
    SELECT 1 a;
  END
  ELSE IF @p_result_sets = 2 BEGIN
    SELECT 1 a;
    SELECT 1 b UNION SELECT 2 b;
  END
END;
```

In this case, you don't know in advance what the result sets will look like, and how many of them you'll get. You will have to run the procedure using [`Statement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--) as follows:

```java
try (CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("...")) {
    boolean results = stmt.execute();

    for (;;) {
        if (results)
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
                // ... Fetch your results here
            }
        else if (stmt.getUpdateCount() != -1) {}
        else
            break;

        results = stmt.getMoreResults();
    }

    // After all results are fetched, you can also retrieve OUT parameters, if applicable
}
```

#### Table-valued functions

The function looks something like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_tables1 ()
RETURNS @out_table TABLE (
  column_value INTEGER
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT @out_table
  VALUES (1)
  RETURN
END
```

In this case, you don't really need a `CallableStatement`. An ordinary `SELECT` statement will do:

```java
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM f_tables1()");
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    // ... Fetch your results here
}
```