# Extract resultset from stored procedure, in Java

Tags: java, db2, resultset

I am executing a stored procedure in Java using the old school way:

```
CallableStatement cs = 
con.prepareCall("schema.procedure("?,?,?,?");
cs.setString(1, "f");
cs.setString(2, "f");
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.CHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.CHAR);
cs.execute();
System.out.println(cs.getString(3));
```

I can retrieve the output columns, but the procedure also returns other results as part of cursor, which i can retrieve using :

```
ResultSet rs= cs.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()) {
for(int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){
rs.getString(i)
```

My question is, can i retrieve both output and the cursor in the same statement ?
Thanks,

Comment: See [java code make a stored procedure return a resultset in DAO layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35612566/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

thanks all , finally this worked, if there is any issue with the approach, please suggest:

```
CallableStatement cs = 
con.prepareCall("schema.procedure("?,?,?,?");
cs.setString(1, "f");
cs.setString(2, "f");
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.CHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.CHAR);
cs.execute();
System.out.println(cs.getString(3));
ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
    for(int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++){
        rs.getString(i)
    }
}
```